# Flag max and min values within group while keeping all records

Tags: postgresql

[preferable_output_of_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pQia.png) 
I have a large dataset that consists of many rows but the two most pertinent are the time and time_id. (see attachment). Time_id can be viewed as the name of the given group and time is the ranking of each row. -- These fields are already set within the dataset and cannot be changed. I want to create a new field that will flag the max and min 'time' of each group but at the same time maintain all records. I want my output to look identical to the attachment. I have been able to easily pull out the max and min values, but I am having issues when I try to keep all records in the group.  Thanks for your help in advance.

```
select 
   time 
  ,time_id 
from my_table
```

Comment: It's better to add the sample data as *formatted* text to your question rather than a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select "time", 
        time_id, 
        case 
          when "time" = max(time) over (partition by time_id) then 'min' 
          when "time" = min(time) over (partition by time_id) then 'max'
          else 'other'
       end
from my_table;
```

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: `time` is a horrible name for a column. Not only because it is a reserved word but also because it doesn't document the meaning of the column. Is it a "start time", an "end time" a "duration", an "offset"...?</sup>